# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException - C# Selenium (Button click)

Tags: c#, selenium

Button click throws an exception:

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException

I tried using wait.Until(), but not working.

```
wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
IWebElement okBtn;

okBtn = wait1.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        try
        {
            okBtn = wait1.Until<IWebElement>((e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    IWebElement element = e.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='btnOk']"));
                    if (element.Displayed)
                    {
                        return element;
                    }
                }

                catch (NoSuchElementException) { }
                catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { }

                return null;
            });
            MouseClick(driver, okBtn);
        }

        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException) { }
        catch (WebDriverException) { }

        return null;
    });
MouseClick(driver, okBtn);
```

The HTML code for the same:

```
<input type="button" value="OK" id="btnOK" onclick="ButtonClick(event);" class="btnnormal" accesskey="x" style="margin: 5px; width: 65px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, like your FindElement is finding a different element to the one you show in your HTML code.

Try to change it to:

```
e.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='btnOK']"));
```

Comment: Here I placed the wrong id.
With the right id too, it gives timeout exception.

Comment: Does `if (element.Displayed)` ever evaluate to True? or is the element hidden somehow?

Comment: Not in all conditions the element is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
wait1.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("btnOK")));
okBtn = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnOk"));
MouseClick(driver, okBtn);
```

Comment: On using this it throws, `NoSuchElementException` or `StaleElementReferenceException`. Hence I had added `try-catch` block for that. But then I faced `TimeoutException`

Comment: @testingqwerty is button clickable manually? TimeoutException in wait.Until here means that this button wasn't clickable for two minutes.

Comment: yes `Timeout.Exception` here means it isn't clicked for 2 minutes.